# Linux Find: How to find .PDF files created after a specific year?

Tags: linux, date, find

I'm using this to list all the .pdf files:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.pdf'
```

I want to add to this, to only list those .pdf files which were created after 2008. Is there a way to do this with find or a better method? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tmp=$(mktemp /tmp/time-XXXXXXXX)
touch -t 200801010000 "$tmp"
find . -type f -iname '*.pdf' -newer "$tmp"
rm "$tmp"
```